# HttpsURLConnection error: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found

Tags: android, android-asynctask, httpurlconnection, httpsurlconnection

Previously, our website was Http and I used AsyncTask and HttpURLConnection to post data with API but now it is Https and when I convert HttpURLConnection to HttpsURLConnection I got this error:

> java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.

What should I do?

Comment: First check ignoring certificate [TrustManager](https://gist.github.com/aembleton/889392)
 .if it works then check with server if it accepts self signed or which parent certificate .Normally phone comes with major CA already .

Comment: [TrustManager](https://gist.github.com/aembleton/889392) works correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To identify the issue, as I mentioned, firstly try ignoring `certificate` using [TrustManager](https://gist.github.com/aembleton/889392) .if it works then check with the `server` if it accepts `self-signed` or which `parent` `certificate`. In General, `devices` already come with preloaded `certificates` by the majority CA .[Here is a detailed link .](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/ca-certificates/+/master/files/)